# Rotatable hash-based duplicate check

Tags: hash, hmac

I want to check duplicates of secret information which is also already encrypted in our database(using ECC algorithm, one of the std curves). plaintexts can be phone numbers, zip codes, etc. Since it's not possible to query encrypted information without doing a full table scan or building on index on long ciphertext, I am thinking of doing something like `hmac(key, plaintext)`. However, since this is susceptible to a rainbow table attack, I am considering if it's better to perform `hmac(salt || key, plaintext)`.

Ofcourse, since this is for "duplicate" checking, I cannot randomly generate a salt, since each secret has to hash into the same hash value. So the idea is to generate, say, 128 salts(that I can rotate regularly) and pick salt using `salt = saltlist[crc32(plaintext) % 128]`, this gives some rainbow table protection + the ability to find duplicates, which still allowing every key and salt to be rotated. Since we have a finite set of salts, we can store it securely in a key store.

Questions:

1. `hmac(salt || key, plaintext)` or `hmac(key, salt || plaintext)`?
2. Does having 128 salts(or any constant value) even provide any additional protection. (if the number of values goes into millions)?
3. Does it even make sense to have an extra secret key, or just `hmac(oneof128salts, plaintext)` provide the same amount of protection?

I am not sure if this is over-engineered?

Comment: 'However, since this is susceptible to a rainbow table attack'; are you assuming that attacker knows the key?  If not, a rainbow table is impossible.

Comment: I am assuming the key leaks.

Comment: Can you (a) describe your schema and intended goal more precisely (what is `secret`? what are the plaintexts you're storing? what are the ciphertexts you're storing, _i.e._ how are the plaintexts encrypted? what duplicates are you trying to detect?), and (b) precisely articulate the capabilities of the adversary?  For instance, does the adversary know `key`?  Does the adversary provide a complete set of plaintexts or ciphertexts up front?  Does the adversary adaptively provide new data after observing how the system reacted to past data?

Comment: Squeamish: Answered a few of your questions

Comment: Squeamish: Answered a few of your questions.
1. `secret` = plaintext
2. using ECC for encryption
3. Adversary questions: Not sure how to answer that. I am assuming the adversary gets access to the entire corpus of hash text + `salt` values OR `key` values(since they are intended to be stored separately). What is the right way to think about this?

Comment: Why are you using anything elliptic-curvy? Can you read https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql and see whether it is applicable?

Comment: Ah! That link is exactly the type of feature I want.

I just realized that I was planning to store the hash key in about the same way as the encryption keys, which would make the whole thing pointless.
But assuming encryption/hash keys were stored separately in key stores, would my scheme be additionally secure in the event of a key leak?